# compiling a c program to use in python code

Tags: c

I have a c program that I need to compile and use in the middle of a python code. it is not c++ program so I assume I should change this syntax for compiling because I get a lot of errors related to not having "main()" in the program which is just because it is a c (not c++)for a x86_64 Mac system?

how should I change this syntax for a program.c code?

> g++ -o program.x program.c

Comment: I suggest you start by looking at e.g. [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/).

Comment: I looked at SWIG a couple of times. The documentation is so massive that I decided to use `Boost::Python` and am not looking back.

Answer (score 1):

Your C code should be compiled into a shared library:

```
gcc -shared -o program.so -Wall -Wextra -fPIC -O2 -DNDEBUG program.c
```

And then you can use [`ctypes`](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html) module to invoke functions in your library from Python.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `.dylib` on a Mac?

Comment: It probably can have any extension since when loading the shared library in Python one can specify the full path. But you may be right in general, I only ever use Macs with Linux.